# Operational Amplifier diagram

Tags: amplifier, power-electronics

I came across several circuit diagram which make  use of op amplifier. What confused me is that in the diagram, there's a basic diagram of an amplifier followed by e.g 1/4 AD8662 (4 of those diagrams). Does that mean the amplifier has 4 channels or does it mean there are 4 physical amplifiers in the circuit?

Comment: 4 OA's per IC ..."quad "

Comment: Kindly explain that further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AD866x comes in  3  varieties x=1,2,4  indicating the number of Op Amps per IC.

Therefore the "1/4 AD8662  "  has an  error.

Comment: Unless it's expecting you to use half an op amp somehow!

Comment: Well, each amp has two inputs!  You could use one per...

Answer (score 1):

The AD8662 is, according to Analog Devices, a dual op-amp - there are two op-amps in the package.  The two op-amps share the power and ground pins but are otherwise independent. The AD8664 is a quad op-amp - four op-amps in one package.

There are many dual (two op-amps) and quad (four op-amps) types.  Many analog comparators and simple logic gates also come two or four-to-a-package, sharing power and ground pins.

Comment: Thank you. This is a better explanation